# Visual C++ Studio 2010 shows build errors for no reason

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, compiler-errors

Apparently I cannot declare an instance of a class in public section of another class.

I've got two classes: Game and ScreenManager. Everything compiles successfully if I remove the following line from Game.h:

```
ScreenManager screenManager;
```

If I don't, I get errors. These are error messages I get on build:

```
1>c:\users\dziku\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test allegro game\test allegro game\game.h(29): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'screenManager'
1>c:\users\dziku\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test allegro game\test allegro game\game.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\dziku\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test allegro game\test allegro game\game.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include"ScreenManager.h"
#include<allegro5\allegro.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>


class Game
{
public:

    static const int WINDOW_WIDTH=800;
    static const int WINDOW_HEIGHT=640;

    static const int FPS=60;
    float FRAME_INTERVAL;

    bool isExiting;

    float currentTime,prevTime,lag;

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* eventQueue;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;

    ScreenManager screenManager;

    Game(void);
    ~Game(void);

    static Game &getInstance();

    void initialize();
    void gameLoop();
    void cleanup();
    void update(ALLEGRO_EVENT &ev);
    void render(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
};
```

And ScreenManager.h:

```
#pragma once

#include"Game.h"
#include<allegro5\allegro.h>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

class ScreenManager
{
public:
    ScreenManager(void);
    ~ScreenManager(void);

    void initialize();
    void update(ALLEGRO_EVENT &ev);
    void render(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
    void unloadContent();

};
```

I don't really get what is going on, I have kept on getting similar errors since yesterday, also in other projects. There is something I must be doing wrong, but I have no clue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: recursive includes - fix with forward class declarations

Comment: You have a circular dependency between these headers.  Game.h includes ScreenManager.h and ScreenManager.h includes Game.h.  Somebody is going to lose.  Well, you.  It is a design flaw.  You need to re-organize the content of these files.  Perhaps use a forward declaration if necessary with the expectation that you might have to use ScreenManager*.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain why does header `"ScreenManager.h"` include heafder `"Game.h"`?

ScreenManager.h:

```
#pragma once

#include"Game.h"
```

If ScreenManager class member functions use some data members of member functions of class Game then you should separate the class definition and uts member functions' definitions. Only declare member functions in the class definitions and their realization place in some separate module. You may make them inline if you want so specifying the function specifier inline.

Or vou can forward declare class Game in header ScreenManager as

```
class Game;
```

and again define member functions of class ScreeManager in a separate module.

Comment: Well, I've just found out that this is the reason why my code doesn't compile.

I included 'Game.h' to access 'isExiting' bool variable from outside Game class but had no other idea how to do it.

Comment: @user264 You can declare all common variables in some third header and include this header in other two.

Comment: @user264 I have seen that this variable is a data member of class Game. If it is used in some method of class ScreenManager then you should separate the class definition and its member functions' definitions.